# Move destructiveButtonTitle to bottom of UIActionSheet

Tags: swift, button, uiactionsheet

I wish to move the cancel button to the bottom of my actionsheet, to be the last button available to the user. I have this code:

```
func openImagePicker(
    actionSheetTitle:String="Choose Image Source",
    cancelTitle:String="Cancel",
    cameraTitle:String="Camera",
    galleryTitle:String="Gallery",
    isImage:Bool=true,
    isMultipleSelection:Bool=false,
    completeHandler:(success:Bool,arrAssert:[TCAsset])->Void,
    failurer:((error:String)->(Void))?=nil)
{

    let actionSheet=UIActionSheet(title: actionSheetTitle, delegate:self, cancelButtonTitle:nil, destructiveButtonTitle:cancelTitle,otherButtonTitles: cameraTitle, galleryTitle)

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
    {
        actionSheet.showInView(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!)
    }
    else
    {
        let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate


        actionSheet.showInView((appDel?.window?.rootViewController?.view)!)
    }
```

Which currently displays the actionsheet like this:

[image]

How can I make it so the cancel button is the last button on the list?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you're targeting iOS 8+, I suggest you implement this using UIAlertController instead since UIActionSheet is deprecated

Comment: @Undeph could you help me implement this with an example? I am fairly new to swift

Comment: Ignore the parameter `destructiveButtonTitle`, then add the button and assign the requested index to `destructiveButtonIndex` explicitly.

Comment: @vadian can you give me an example please?

Comment: The method `addButtonWithTitle:` returns the index where the button is going to be inserted. Add `Cancel` at the end and assign the result of the `addButton..`  method to `destructiveButtonIndex`.

Comment: @vadian I still dont understand sorry, can you give me a coded example? I am new to swift :(

Comment: Set `destructiveButtonTitle` to `nil` and add the line `destructiveButtonIndex = actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle(cancelTitle)`. To handle the index properly you have to check the index of the pressed button against `destructiveButtonIndex`. But if you are new to Swift forget the legacy API and use `UIAlertController`.

Comment: @vadian where do I add the line sorry?

Comment: Right after creating `actionSheet`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116724/discussion-between-james-patterson-and-vadian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that there's a very simple answer to this:

You can use destructiveButtonIndex to set the index of the destructiveButton to wherever you want.

```
actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't implement your completion blocks, but this should get you started:

```
func openImagePicker(
        actionSheetTitle:String="Choose Image Source",
        cancelTitle:String="Cancel",
        cameraTitle:String="Camera",
        galleryTitle:String="Gallery",
        isImage:Bool=true,
        isMultipleSelection:Bool=false,
        completeHandler:(success:Bool,arrAssert:[Bool])->Void,
        failurer:((error:String)->(Void))?=nil)
    {
        let sheet = UIAlertController(title: actionSheetTitle, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: cameraTitle, style: .Default, handler: { _ in
            // Code to execute when "Camera" is pressed
            print("Camera selected")
        }))
        sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: galleryTitle, style: .Default, handler: { _ in
            // Code to execute when "Gallery" is pressed
            print("Gallery selected")
        }))
        sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: cancelTitle, style: .Destructive, handler: { _ in
            // Code to execute when "Cancel" is pressed
            print("Cancel selected")
        }))
        presentViewController(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The function has to reside in an instance of `UIViewController` (since it will call `presentViewController(...`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to implement but am I faced with lots of errors, not sure how to implement this properly :( Is there no simple fix to move the cancel button to bottom of my list and simply change its font colour to red?